# Basic C linked list syntax error

Tags: c, syntax, linked-list

Note: I already got the intended function to work with my own code, but I saw a tutorial on another website and am wondering why it doesn't work.

https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

The premise is as follows:

I'm playing around with a very basic linked list:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

I am trying to have a function remove an entry by value. It is as follows:

```
int remove_by_value(node_t ** head, int val) {
    for(head = &node_t; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next){
        if ((*head)->val == val) {
            *head = (*head)->next;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error when calling this function, namely:

```
"prog.c:35:17: error: expected expression before 'node_t'
 for(head = &node_t; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next){
 ^"
```

Any ideas? Is this just a simple syntax error that I'm not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: What is this `head = &node_t` for?

Comment: In addition to the syntax errors, your logic for splicing out an element is wrong.

Comment: try "for (; ...)", i..e leave off tghe "head = &node_t")

Comment: so many things are wrong in this code, it's hard to pick where to start

Comment: I actually took this method off of a website I saw:

https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

I've gotten the code to work using a different approach, but am wondering why the approach shown in this website doesn't work.

Comment: @riceman89 Why do you conclude that the approach in the website doesn't work? It's more logical to conclude that you have not adapted the contained info correctly. In this case the (first) error has already been pointed out: you are using a type, `node_t`, as a variable.

Comment: if node_t is a type, rather than a variable, then taking its address (&node_t) doesn't make any sense at all. So the compiler chokes.

Comment: Check out here - [Linked list operations in C](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/09/c-program-to-create-and-traverse-singly-linked-list.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the root of the problem is that `node_t` is a type, not a variable and cannot take the address of a type.

The following code cleanly compiles.

be sure to check the logic,

1. for first iteration of the loop when `head` = NULL or only one struct in linked list
2. check logic for when desired struct is either last or next to last in the linked list

here is the code:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;


int remove_by_value(node_t ** head, int val)
{
    int retVal = -1;  // initialize to failed
    node_t  *previousNode = *head;
    node_t  *currentNode = *head;

    for(;
        previousNode && currentNode; // assure something to test
        previousNode = currentNode,  // update the pointers
        currentNode = currentNode->next )
    {
        if (currentNode->val == val)
        {
            previousNode->next = currentNode->next;
            retVal = 0; // indicate success
            break;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
} // end function: remove_by_value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. Didn't realize that I was trying to perform variable calls on a typedef. Very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment on the [accepted answer](/a/34779554/2599567) written by @[user3629249](/users/3629249/user3629249):
That code is even worse than the original (except that it would compile).

I'd suggest something like this:

```
node_t *remove_by_value(node_t **head, int val)
{
    node_t *ret = NULL;

    for (; *head; head = &((*head)->next))
    {
            if ((*head)->val == val)
            {
                    ret = *head;
                    *head = (*head)->next;
                    break;
            }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This code correctly removes the element from the beginning, middle and end of the list. In addition it gives the caller the chance to free the unlinked node.

Comment: What would you propose instead as a cleaner way of writing it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot shorter, elegant, and works properly. Much appreciated!

Comment: I wrote my answer in way I did because: 1) avoided changing the OPs function signature, 2) did not pass the selected struct pointer to free() as the OP did not specify that the linked list consists of memory allocations from the malloc() family 3) this posted answer is changing the callers' pointer, even when the selected struct is NOT the first struct in the linked list.

Comment: @user3629249 nevertheless the result of your changes is e.g. that the first node cannot be deleted. There is a reason why the address of the listhead pointer is passed to the function.

Comment: I did say to check the algorithm for the edge cases (as it may not be correct)

Comment: @user3629249 No offence mate, I simply wonder why you've changed the original algorithm which was perfectly fine, except from the "head = &node_t;" fragment which prevented it from compilation.

Answer (score 0):

1) The error you are getting was pointed out by iharob already.
2) I can understand that out of this head =&t_node you want head to point at the head of your list. a static variable may be needed in your file to be able to use this then you can point head correctly